# Regex exclude characters from inner group match

Tags: regex, regex-group

I would like to integrate an exclude from inner group email regex match, i ve tryed already to **exclude** character `<` & `>` to exclude from group `[\p{L}\p{S}][^<>]` not successful.

```
^(?!.{256})(?:[\p{L}]+(?:\.[\p{L}]+)*@(?:(?:[\p{L}](?:[\p{L}\p{S}]*[\p{L}])?\.)+[\p{L}](?:[\p{L}\p{S}]*[\p{L}])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\]))$
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\p{S}` matches `<` and `>` One option is to rule them out after the @ sign using a negative lookahead `@(?!\S*[<>])` or add it after the start of the string  https://regex101.com/r/SYemaL/1

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to be my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\p{S}` can also match `<` and `>` If you don't want to match those, and keep using the character class `[\p{L}\p{S}]` you can use a negative lookahead to rule out the matches for those characters.

As the part before @ can not match angle brackets, you can add another negative lookahad to the start of the string asserting not `<` or `>` to the right.

```
^(?!\S*[<>])(?!.{256})(?:[\p{L}]+(?:\.[\p{L}]+)*@(?:(?:[\p{L}](?:[\p{L}\p{S}]*[\p{L}])?\.)+[\p{L}](?:[\p{L}\p{S}]*[\p{L}])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\]))$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mCMU7w/1).

Answer (score 0):

An in-line approach is to exclude `<>` from the symbol class.
In order to do that replace `[\p{L}\p{S}]` in 2 places with `(?:\p{L}|[^\P{S}<>])`

Where the `\p{L}` has to be explicitly or'd.
However inside classes each item is or'd anyway, and not too efficiently.

```
^(?!.{256})(?:[\p{L}]+(?:\.[\p{L}]+)*@(?:(?:[\p{L}](?:(?:\p{L}|[^\P{S}<>])*[\p{L}])?\.)+[\p{L}](?:(?:\p{L}|[^\P{S}<>])*[\p{L}])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\]))$
```

https://regex101.com/r/6OPVA8/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a [*negated intersection*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html):

```
[\p{L}\p{S}&&[^<>]]
```

Which subtracts `<>` characters, specified in an inner character class, from the outer character class of `\p{L}\p{S}`.